Batch cmd List folders and sort them descending order
I want to list just the folders in a given path (not files and not subfolders) and create a text file from the listed names without any other info besides the names of the folders and to sort them descending of Date Modified. (on top the latest below last)
Can anyone tell me how? Thanks
This is listing without sorting
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

dir "C:\FOlder" /A:D /B > List.txt

EndLocal


Ah so simple, no need help
dir /o-d "C:\FOlder" /A:D /B > List.txt

